# Webpack aliases starting with $ (dollar sign)

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possible to define [webpack aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) with a dollar sign (`$`) at the beginning, so I can reference e.g. `import foo from '$utils/foo'`? Seems like the sign is considered special based on  `A trailing $ can also be added to the given object's keys to signify an exact match`. I've tried to switch from having my aliases starting from `@` to starting from `$` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

define the aliases in the `resolve.alias` property in your webpack configuration file

```
module.exports = {
 
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "$utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils")
    }
  }
};
```